# Rails/Authlogic: restrict login/session to one record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, devise

I've taken over a membership database for a small organization.  The data is quite out of date, it's just name and address information (no email addresses). I've ported it into a Rails3 app.

I want the members to be able to log in and update their own information. How would I do that with Authlogic (or Devise for that matter)?

Say I have a "Household" model.  Should I add the Authlogic fields into this model, or is it better to keep separate Users and Sessions models?

How would I make it so that user A can only access views for user A?

Any nifty ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could setup model User as describe in Authlogic [tutorial](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) and set an 1 to 1 relation with "Household" or make household 'act_as_authentic' (it's your coiche) .

For restrict access you could use a simple before_filter in your user or household countroller (require_user as usual).

in the edit and update action  set @user (or @household) = current_user is safe enough .